# Splitting Multiline XML tag into multiple Nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a XML below, where new lines are added after each line at Note__c tag. I need to produce the XML by splitting them into multiple Note__c tags.
Input XML-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<snotification>
 <data>
  <schema>yify-xjmoeLTbNXA560rHQ</schema>
  <payload>
   <Note__c>01/15/2020
   123456
   DFGRTE766
   6tgBFR</Note__c>
   <Line_Length__c>72.0</Line_Length__c>
   <CreatedById>00554000003OENsAAO</CreatedById>
   <Contact_Name__c/>
   <Sent_By_Name__c>SBM</Sent_By_Name__c>
   <CreatedDate>2020-01-15T16:10:40.551Z</CreatedDate>
   <Order_Number__c>14831</Order_Number__c>
   <Does_not_require_reformatting__c>false</Does_not_require_reformatting__c>
  </payload>
  <event>
   <replayId>139219</replayId>
  </event>
 </data>
 <channel>/event/Order_Note__e</channel>
</snotification>
```

Where Note__c contains multiple strings with new line added after each(except the last one)
Expected Output -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<snotification>
 <data>
  <schema>yify-xjmoeLTbNXA560rHQ</schema>
  <payload>
      <Notes>
   <Note__c>01/15/2020</Note__c>
   <Note__c>123456</Note__c>
   <Note__c>DFGRTE766</Note__c>
   <Note__c>6tgBFR</Note__c>
      </Notes>
   <Line_Length__c>72.0</Line_Length__c>
   <CreatedById>00554000003OENsAAO</CreatedById>
   <Contact_Name__c/>
   <Sent_By_Name__c>SBM</Sent_By_Name__c>
   <CreatedDate>2020-01-15T16:10:40.551Z</CreatedDate>
   <Order_Number__c>14831</Order_Number__c>
   <Does_not_require_reformatting__c>false</Does_not_require_reformatting__c>
  </payload>
  <event>
   <replayId>139219</replayId>
  </event>
 </data>
 <channel>/event/Order_Note__e</channel>
</snotification>
```

I have written this XSLT but it is missing few tags under the payload element -

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="snotification/data/payload">
    <Notes>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Note__c,'\n')">
                <Note__c>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Note__c>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Notes>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output of this-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<snotification>
   <data>
      <schema>yify-xjmoeLTbNXA560rHQ</schema>
      <Notes>
         <Note__c>01/15/2020</Note__c>
         <Note__c>   123456</Note__c>
         <Note__c>   DFGRTE766</Note__c>
         <Note__c>   6tgBFR</Note__c>
      </Notes>
      <event>
         <replayId>139219</replayId>
      </event>
   </data>
   <channel>/event/Order_Note__e</channel>
</snotification>
```

not sure what is missing.

Thanks
Sugata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XSLT to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="snotification/data/payload/Note__c">
        <Notes>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\n')">
                <Note__c>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </Note__c>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Notes>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be as desired.

Comment: Thank you zx485 for help, it worked like a charm. I have also created a Java stringtokenizer soln. for this. This XSLT is more easy than that.